# jQuery Fire a AJAX call from the returned array from a AJAX call and get the resulting array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am firing an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call on page load and getting an array back. Now for each element called `groupId` present in the array, I have to fire another [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call to get the group name and group notes.

Now I need to create a final array that would have the array returned from the first [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call and merged with the corresponding group name and info returned from the second call.

This is the array returned from the first [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call:

```
[{
  "customMessage": "THis is the first message",
  "groupIdx": 13
}, {
  "customMessage": "This is the second message",
  "groupIdx": 14
}]
```

Which I am getting by doing:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '<html:rewrite page="/rest/pre-visit-instruction/list"/>',
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data) {
  vueInst.preVisitInstructions = data;
});
```

Now to this I am appending a `.each` function and calling another [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)call.

This is the final code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '<html:rewrite page="/rest/pre-visit-instruction/list"/>',
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    vueInst.preVisitInstructions = data;
  }).each(dataObj, function(j, data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '<html:rewrite page="/rest/group/"/>' + data.groupIdx + '/info',
        dataType: "json"
      }).
```

My question is: How do I get the data returned from the `.each` function and append it to the original object?

Comment: Add a `.done()` to your second AJAX call just as you have in your first?  Only in the second one, `.push()` elements onto the existing array instead of setting the entire array?

Comment: Chaining an `.each` to the `.done` method will not work on the results of the ajax call. Do the `.each` inside the `.done` method were you have access to the `data`.

Comment: Is this what you are suggesting for .each inside .done. ANd also how do i use .push here    $.ajax({  
type: "GET",
url: '<html:rewrite page="/rest/pre-visit-instruction/list"/>',
dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data) {  
vueInst.preVisitInstructions = data;
$.each(dataObj, function(j, data) {  
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '<html:rewrite page="/rest/group/"/>' + data.groupIdx + '/info',
dataType: "json"
})

Comment: sorry the editing is off and i am not able to fix it

Comment: Second ajax call is in .each in the above code. Json data from the second call should be something like   {{ groupId:4 groupName:ABD groupNotes:THis is a note}, { groupId:5 groupName:SDF groupNotes:THis is a note},

Comment: Now i need the data from one and two to be appended in a single array

Answer (score -1):

`$.each()` function must be inside of `.done()` function.

**Update:** According to the last comment:

You should use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
data.data = response2.filter(function(x) {
  return x.groupId === data.groupIdx;
});
```

Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var vueInst = {
    preVisitInstructions: []
  };
  var result = [];

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/17455e3ef90fb3cf096d1f051d4331e5/raw/ad51c85e7722a83e7085ad63e26a524b769efe50/firstData.json",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(response1) {
    $.each(response1, function(j, data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/e610dd23f830b108bc1e24c78f66b3b6/raw/54851535eedd1e94a1a944ddf3d63412e83349f8/secondData.json",
        dataType: "json"
      }).done(function(response2) {
        data.data = response2.filter(function(x) {
          return x.groupId === data.groupIdx;
        });
        result.push(data);
      });
      vueInst.preVisitInstructions = result;
    });
  });
  $("#btnCheck").on("click", function() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(vueInst.preVisitInstructions));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnCheck">Check data</button>
```

The result should be:

```
[{
    "customMessage": "THis is the first message",
    "groupIdx": 13,
    "data": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "customMessage": "This is the second message",
    "groupIdx": 14,
    "data": [{
        "groupId": 14,
        "groupName": "Test 1",
        "groupNotes": "THis is a note"
      },
      {
        "groupId": 14,
        "groupName": "Test 2",
        "groupNotes": "THis is a note"
      },
      {
        "groupId": 14,
        "groupName": "Test 3",
        "groupNotes": "THis is a note"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Danny. What this is doing is appending the data from second response (response2) to every row in the first object. But what I want is to have only that row to be appended where the groupId of the first one matches the groupId of the second one.

Comment: @user8895989 I've updated my answer. Let me know if this works properly.